# Linking to Categories Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I'm creating a module for joomla 2.5. With it i need to create links to joomla categories

At the moment I am doing it like this:

```
$link = "index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=".$cat->id;
```

This works, but I want to use the SEF URL's that joomla gives to each category.  Ie:

*http;//www.website.co.uk/category/*

Our website never shows more than one step in the URL so if the structure is: Cat1->Cat2->Cat3

The URL will only show: *http;//www.website.co.uk/Cat3/*

```
$link = JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=".$cat->id);
```

only results in a link to the home page.  How can I get it to link to the category?

Comment: Are any of these associated with a menu item?

Comment: Potentially, though not necessarily.  Which is why I'm creating this mod in the first place haha